# Is it possible to load balance Azure Queues or Topics using Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe, azure-traffic-manager

I have read that it is possible to use Azure Traffic Manager to load balance (or failover) web apps and cloud services.

Is it possible to use Azure Traffic Manager to add failover capability to Azure Queues or Topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature is used for Azure Web Apps (former Azure Web Sites), Cloud Services and Virtual Machines.